# Is it necessary to invent IDs for wxErlang widgets?

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets, wxerlang

I've been poking around with Erlang's `wx` module and [this](http://wxerlang.dougedmunds.com/first-window/laying-out-the-wx-window-part-1/laying-out-the-wx-window-part-2) tutorial. I haven't used wxwidgets before, so maybe this is just how it's done, but this code seems really terrible to me:

```
%% create widgets
    T1001 = wxTextCtrl:new(Panel, 1001,[]),
    ST2001 = wxStaticText:new(Panel, 2001,"Output Area", []),
    B101  = wxButton:new(Panel, 101, [{label, "&Countdown"}]),
    B102  = wxButton:new(Panel, ?wxID_EXIT, [{label, "E&xit"}]),
    wxFrame:show(Frame),
```

Do people really have to assign widget IDs to widgets when creating them? Is it normal to name the variable that points to the widget after the widget's ID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about Erlang but in C++ (and in the other bindings I know about) it's often preferable to use `wxID_ANY` as the widget id, meaning that you don't care about its specific value, and then use `Connect()` to handle events from the widget. Explicit ids may be convenient if you need to find the widget by its id later (although you can also use widget names for this) or if you need a consecutive range for ids (e.g. it would make sense to use ids 100, 101, ..., 109 for the buttons of a calculator as you could then easily deduce each buttons value from its id) but there is no need to always use them.

As for the naming, there is, of course, no need to use this strange convention (and a quick look at the tutorial shows that it's a personal preference of the author -- which, needless to say, I don't share).

Comment: Thanks. The naming convention suggested to me that maybe the programmer would have to be able to tell what the IDs of the objects were at some point in the future. It's good to know that it's not idiomatic in wx-land.

Answer (score 5):

Like VZ mentioned above, you can use wxID_ANY if you won't need to lookup a widget by its id later.

However, I believe that not only it's not normal to name the variables after the ids, but rather it's a very bad idea to do so. **Name your variables according to their meaning and not using some obscure id**.

Also, you'd better define the ids you need and give them proper (semantic) names, so that they are defined in only one place and you can later easily change the ids without affecting your program at all, like this:

```
-define(ID_TEXT_CTRL, 1001).
-define(ID_OUTPUT_AREA, 2001).
-define(ID_COUNTDOWN_BUTTON, 101).
-define(ID_EXIT_BUTTON, ?wxID_EXIT).

TextCtrl = wxTextCtrl:new(Panel, ?ID_TEXT_CTRL,[]),
OutputArea = wxStaticText:new(Panel, ?ID_OUTPUT_AREA,"Output Area", []),
CountdownButton  = wxButton:new(Panel, ?ID_COUNTDOWN_BUTTON, [{label, "&Countdown"}]),
ExitButton  = wxButton:new(Panel, ?ID_EXIT_BUTTON, [{label, "E&xit"}])
```

You may put the definitions either in your `.erl` file, if it's only one, or in an `.hrl` file, which you'll have to include in all your GUI-related `.erl` files.

Comment: So is it normal to have to look up widgets by their ids? In what sorts of situations would one have to do that?

Comment: It depends on your wxErlang style. If you use one wx_object behavior per widget you probably won't have to look up widgets by their id. However, if you just write one module, containing the creation and handling of all widgets and events, then you may create a widget in one function and then need to use it in another function. How will you find the widget, if not by id?

Answer (score 1):

No. The cases in which you would want to look something up by ID are roughly the same cases in which you would want to look something up by ID in C++. This applies across any widget library I can think of -- every time you react to a signal coded `some_standard_button_name` and matches a label like `?wxID_OK` you are waiting for a numeric ID that is represented by a label hidden by a macro. Most GUI libraries do a lot of preprocessing to wash this out, so often you don't notice it (in the case of sooper-dooper libraries like Qt its still going on, just in the background, and all of your code is [run through a precompiler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) before it becomes "real" C++...).

So how do you get a hold of a wx thingy that's been created? By using its returned reference.

Almost every `wx*:new()` call returns an object reference[note1]. This is an abstract reference (internally a tuple, but don't count on that) with enough information for the Erlang bindings and the Wx system processes to talk unambiguously about specific Wx objects that have been created. Passing these references around is the typical way of accessing Wx objects later on:

```
GridSz = wxFlexGridSizer:new(2, 2, 4, 4),
ok = wxFlexGridSizer:setFlexibleDirection(GridSz, ?wxHORIZONTAL),
ok = wxFlexGridSizer:addGrowableCol(GridSz, 1),
```

A less obvious case, though, is when you want something like a grid of input fields that you can cycle through or pull by key value:

```
Scripts = [katakana, hiragana, kanji, latin],
Ilks    = [family, given, middle, maiden],
Rows    = [{Tag, j(J, Tag)} || Tag <- Scripts],
Cols    = [{Tag, j(J, Tag)} || Tag <- Ilks],
{GridSz, Fields} = zxw:text_input_grid(Dialog, Rows, Cols),

% Later on, extracting only present values as

Keys = [{S, I} || S <- Scripts, I <- Ilks],
Extract =
    fun(Key, Acc) ->
        case wxTextCtrl:getValue(proplists:get_value(Key, Fields)) of
            ""  -> Acc;
            Val -> [{Key, Val} | Acc]
        end
    end,
NewParts = lists:foldl(Extract, [], Keys),
```

And so on. ([zxw:text_input_grid/3 definition](https://github.com/zxq9/zxWidgets/blob/master/src/zxw.erl#L173-L214), and [docs](http://zxq9.com/zx_widgets/))

The one time you really do want to reference an object by its ID and not its object reference is the same as in C++: when you are listening for a specific click event:

```
{AddressPicker, _, _, AddressSz} =
    zxw:list_picker(Frame,
                    ?widgetADDRESS, ?addADDRESS, ?delADDRESS,
                    AddressHeader, Addresses, j(J, address)),
```

And then later in the message handling loop of the generic wx_object:

```
handle_event(Wx = #wx{id    = Id,
                      event = #wxCommand{type = command_button_clicked}},
             State) ->
    case Id of
        ?editNAME     -> {noreply, edit_name(State)};
        ?editDOB      -> {noreply, edit_dob(State)};
        ?editPORTRAIT -> {noreply, edit_portrait(State)};
        ?addCONTACT   -> {noreply, add_contact_info(State)};
        ?delCONTACT   -> {noreply, del_contact_info(State)};
        ?addADDRESS   -> {noreply, add_address_info(State)};
        ?delADDRESS   -> {noreply, del_address_info(State)};
        _ ->
            ok = unexpected(Wx),
            {noreply, State}
    end;
handle_event(Wx = #wx{id    = Id,
                      event = #wxList{type      = command_list_item_selected,
                                      itemIndex = Index}},
             State) ->
    case Id of
        ?widgetCONTACT -> {noreply, update_selection(contact, Index, State)};
        ?widgetADDRESS -> {noreply, update_selection(address, Index, State)};
        _ ->
            ok = unexpected(Wx),
            {noreply, State}
    end;
```

The first clause deals specifically with clicks on non-standard buttons, and the second with list-control widget selection events to do some arbitrary things in the interface. While unwrapping the `#wx{}` event record isn't very visually appealing, using matching in clause formation makes this GUI code *much* easier to understand during maintenance than the gigantic cascade of checks, exception catches and follow-on `if elif elif elif elif...`, `switch` or `case..break`, etc. type code necessary in languages that lack matching.

In the above case all the specific IDs are labeled as macros, *exactly* the same way this is done in Wx in C++ and other C++ widget kits. *Most* of the time your needs are served simply by using the standard pre-defined Wx button types and reacting to them accordingly; the example above is from code that is forced to dive a bit below that because of some specific interface requirements (and the equivalent C++ code winds up essentially the same, but dramatically more verbose to accomplish the same task).

Some platforms in slightly higher level languages have different ways of dealing with the identity issue. iOS and Android widget kits (and QtQuick, for that matter) hide this detail behind something like a slightly more universally useful object reference rather than depending on IDs. That is to say those widget kits essentially store all widgets created in a hash of {ID => ObjReference}, pick the ID out of every signal, retrieve the object reference before passing control to your handling callbacks, and return the reference stored in the hash instead of just passing the ID through directly.

That's slick, but its not the way older widget kits bound to C-style enums-as-labels code work. When its all said and done computers still have only one real type: integers -- we invent all sorts of other stuff on top of this and enjoy the illusion of types and other fun.

We could do this ID-to-reference thing in Erlang also, but the way WxErlang code is typically written is to follow the C++ tradition of using object IDs behind macro labels for events you can't avoid identifying uniquely, and object references and standard labels for everything else.

The zx_widgets library employed above is a set of pre-defined meta-widgets that cover some of the most common cases of boilerplate field construction and return data structures that are easy to handle functionally. The OOP style of Wx isn't a very natural fit for Erlang in some ways (the looooooongest functions you'll ever write in Erlang are likely to be GUI code for this reason), so an extra layer is sometimes necessary to make the logic-bearing code jibe with the rest of Erlang. GUI code is pretty universally annoying, though, in any language and in any environment.

[note1: *There are some weird, uncomfortable cases where a few C++-style mysteries leak through the bindings into your Erlang code, such as the magical environment creation procedure involved in using 2D graphics DC canvasses and whatnot.*]